# Unable to update Nuget modules when loading a Solution into VS2017 15.4.1

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution with three projects that user .net core (v1.1) IdentityServer (1.1.0) and BrainTree (v3.7.0) amongst a few more.  I can load the solution into VS2017, but none of the dependencies are valid.  They all have the small yellow triangle.

[image]

So I right-click on Dependencies, select manage packages and try to install them.  When I do I get the following error:

> Error     The given key was not present in the dictionary.            0

Under output I get more detail, but still no clarity:

```
Restoring packages for C:\Users\justin.hull\Source\Workspaces\Enterprise Repository\Web Applications\JPPAIdentityServer\src\JPPAMobileWebAPI\JPPAMobileAPI.csproj...
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at NuGet.Commands.TransitiveNoWarnUtils.ExtractTransitiveNoWarnProperties(RestoreTargetGraph targetGraph, String parentProjectName, HashSet`1 parentProjectWideNoWarn, Dictionary`2 parentPackageSpecificNoWarn, Dictionary`2 warningPropertiesCache)
   at NuGet.Commands.TransitiveNoWarnUtils.CreateTransitiveWarningPropertiesCollection(IEnumerable`1 targetGraphs, PackageSpec parentProjectSpec)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCollectorLogger.get_TransitiveWarningPropertiesCollection()
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCollectorLogger.IsWarningSuppressed(IRestoreLogMessage message)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCollectorLogger.LogAsync(IRestoreLogMessage message)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCollectorLogger.LogAsync(ILogMessage message)
   at NuGet.Commands.Extensions.<LogMessagesAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.<ValidateRestoreGraphsAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.<ExecuteAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<ExecuteAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<CompleteTaskAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.<RunWithoutCommit>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.DependencyGraphRestoreUtility.<PreviewRestoreAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<PreviewBuildIntegratedProjectActionsAsync>d__74.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.NuGetPackageManager.<PreviewInstallPackageAsync>d__65.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.<GetActionsAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at NuGet.PackageManagement.UI.UIActionEngine.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<<PerformActionImplAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
Time Elapsed: 00:00:02.6872367
========== Finished ==========
```

I did some searching and while I found something that relates to Hololens and Unity, I'm using neither.  I am on the latest update of Studio, I upgraded .net core to 2.0 and this version of windows:

[image]

I've tried manually changing the global.json and the csproj files per some ideas and no go there.  Anyone find a solution to this issue for going back to 2015 is not a viable option.

Comment: What happens if you remove all/any reference(s) and add them back directly from the package manager?

Comment: Maybe you've got my case:
With VS2017 Framework 3.5 is replaced with Framework 4.0 "implicitly" (you can't choose, can't prevent).
I had same thing after installing VS2017 next to existing VS2015. The only thing that gave me 3.5 back was to reinstall VS2015 again and then to work with VS2017.

Comment: @j.hull, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved your issue? If not, Please let me know the latest information about this issue.

Comment: My apologies for not responding.  It was determined that at the time, we would not upgrade the code as higher priority projects hit the schedule.  I will, when it get quiet try again with these ideas.

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to update Nuget modules when loading a Solution into VS2017 15.4.1

You must created this .NET core project with Visual Studio **2015**, then open it with Visual Studio **2017**. The .net core version for Visual Studio 2015 is `1.0.0-preview`, after upgrade the project to Visual Studio 2017, the target framework will be convert to `.NET Standard 1.6` base on the compatibility, you can check the compatibility list on [.NET Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/):

[image]

Then you check the **Dependencies** info about [Microsoft.AspNetCore 1.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore/1.1.0) and [IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation 1.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation/1.1.0), both of them have a dependency:

```
NETStandard.Library (>= 1.6.1)
```

[image]

However, the default version of `NETStandard.Library` is **1.6.0** after upgrade the project to Visual Studio 2017, which cause the incompatibility. That is the reason why you got the small yellow triangles.

**To resolve this issue**, you can uninstall the packages `Microsoft.AspNetCore 1.1.0`, `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation 1.1.0`, instead of install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore` **1.0.6** and `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation` **1.0.5**, which have the dependency is `NETStandard.Library (>= 1.6.0)`.

Alternatively, if you want to keep use the previous version 1.1.0 for `Microsoft.AspNetCore` and `IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation`, you can update the package `NETStandard.Library` from 1.6 to **2.0** on **Visual Studio 2015**, then open the project with Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on VS2017 version 15.4.1 with NuGet Package version 4.4.0. It seems to be a bug. A workaround is to change the assembly name of the project to match the actual name of the project.

For more info, please refer to [Nuget - Issue 6020](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6020)